# Roblox Studio Admin GUI set player scores

Tags: lua, roblox

Hi there i'm a little stuck on how i would set a players cash through a admin gui i'm not to familiar with this language and could use a little help. 
here is what the gui looks like

[GUI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwMLJ.png)

[Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCqOG.png)

[code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G55Md.png)

here is what i have so far not sure if im on the right lines or not aha

```
button = script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    local stat = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stat.Parent = script.Parent.Parent.casgplayertext.Text

    stat.Name = "Cash"
    stat.Value = script.Parent.Parent.cashetxt
    game.Players.childAdded:connect()
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics values should be children of a model or folder object named 'leaderstats', located in the player (for instance: Player1>leaderstats>Cash). So you need a script that creates this 'leaderstats'-named object with the statistics you want. So you would get something like this:

```
local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

local function initializeLeaderstats(player)
    local stats = Instance.new("Folder")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local cashStat = Instance.new("IntValue", stats)
    cashStat.Name = "Cash"
    stats.Parent = player
end

players.PlayerAdded:connect(initializeLeaderstats)
```

Then you need some code to manipulate the value of someones cash statistic in another script. You can write a function that uses 2 parameters: the player name and the amount of cash.

```
local players = game:WaitForChild("Players")

local function setCashValue(playerName, value)
    local player = players:FindFirstChild(playerName)
    if player then
        local leaderStats = player.leaderstats
        local cashStat = leaderStats.Cash
        cashStat.Value = value
    end
end
```

You can call this function when you have clicked the 'Submit' button with the 2 parameters: the player name and the amount of cash.